# Fill empty cells in a single row with first non-empty left value

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(C1 = rep(c("A", "B"), 20),
                  C2 = c(NA, rep(c("J", "K"), 19), "J"), 
                  C3 = c(NA, rep(c("J", "K"), 19), "J"),
                  C4 = rep(c("C", "D"), 20))
```

Which gives me the following two first rows:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NA | NA | C |
| B | J | J | D |

Is there any function that allows to fill columns `C2` and `C3` with the first left non-empty cell, i.e., with the `A` value? (and so on; if for example I had column `C5` with `NA` it would fill this cell with the `C` value)

My try was not so 'pipeable':

```
require(tidyverse)
df[1,] <- (as.data.frame(unlist(df[1,])) %>% fill(`unlist(df[1, ])`))[,1]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `na.locf` across the rows:

```
library(zoo)
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))))
##    C1 C2 C3 C4
## 1   A  A  A  C
## 2   B  J  J  D
## 3   A  K  K  C
## 4   B  J  J  D
## 5   A  K  K  C
## 6   B  J  J  D
## ...
```

It can also be written as:

```
df |>
  apply(1, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE) |>
  t() |>
  data.frame()
```

### Update

Have incorporated suggestion from TarJae.

Answer (score 1):

First `t`ransposing to wide format, then `fill`ing, finally transposing back to long. Renaming rows and columns along the way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(t(df)) %>% 
  fill(1:nrow(df)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame(row.names = 1:nrow(df)) %>% 
  rename_with(\(x) colnames(df))
   C1 C2 C3 C4
1   A  A  A  C
2   B  J  J  D
3   A  K  K  C
4   B  J  J  D
...
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to pivot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>%
  fill(value, .direction = "down") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-rn)

#   C1    C2    C3    C4   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     A     A     C    
# 2 B     J     J     D    
# 3 A     K     K     C    
# 4 B     J     J     D    
# 5 A     K     K     C
```